# Emacs lisp: Debugging timers?

Tags: emacs, asynchronous, timer, elisp

In emacs lisp a form of pseudo-asynchronicity can be achieved through the `run-with-timer` and `run-with-async-timer` commands. Think e.g. of the following simple countdown timer:

```
(defun -c (i)
 (cond 
  ((= i 0)  (error "TESTERROR"))
  (t
   (message "Countdown at %d" i)
   (run-with-timer 1 nil '-c (1- i)))))
```

Running `(-c 3)` will display the messages

```
Countdown at 3
Countdown at 2
Countdown at 1
```

The signaled error will silently be ignored.

Is there some way in emacs lisp to get error reporting for such timers, preferably with complete stacktrace?

Comment: As sds points out, this was a bug (in my opinion) and I fixed it a few months ago in Emacs's trunk.

Answer (score 0):

I do not observe the behavior you describe with Emacs 24.3.50.3:

```
(lexical-let ((countdown 3) timer)
  (defun countdown ()
    (message "countdown %d" countdown)
    (when (zerop (decf countdown))
      (cancel-timer timer)
      (error "BOOM")))
  (setq timer (run-with-timer 1 1 'countdown)))
```

I see in echo area and in `*Messages*`:

```
countdown 3
countdown 2
countdown 1
Entering debugger...
```

and then in `*Backtrace*`:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "BOOM")
  signal(error ("BOOM"))
  error("BOOM")
  (progn (cancel-timer (symbol-value G66502)) (error "BOOM"))
  (if (zerop (let* ((v G66503)) (set v (1- (symbol-value G66503))))) (progn (cancel-timer (symbol-value G66502)) (error "BOOM")))
  (lambda (G66502 G66503) (message "countdown %d" (symbol-value G66503)) (if (zerop (let* ((v G66503)) (set v (1- (symbol-value G66503))))) (progn (cancel-timer (symbol-value G66502)) (error "BOOM"))))(--timer-- --countdown--)
  apply((lambda (G66502 G66503) (message "countdown %d" (symbol-value G66503)) (if (zerop (let* ((v G66503)) (set v (1- (symbol-value G66503))))) (progn (cancel-timer (symbol-value G66502)) (error "BOOM")))) --timer-- --countdown-- nil)
  countdown()
  apply(countdown nil)
  byte-code("r\301\302H\303H\"\210)\301\207" [timer apply 5 6] 4)
  timer-event-handler([t 20941 51022 556644 1 countdown nil nil 176000])
```

Comment: Thanks... I compiled emacs from source now and it works now. In order to get the stacktrace though, I had to do `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` in addition though. Do you have `debug-on-error` enabled by default?